# Random sphere packing

Tags: approximation, computational-geometry

Suppose we have a large box. And we place non-overlapping spheres randomly inside until there isn't room for any more. Spheres are placed uniformly on random inside, no gravity. The box is much larger then the spheres. What is the expected percentage of volume occupied by the spheres?

I just need a very rough answer, I wrote an algorithm and got a very low answer, I want to know *roughly* what I should get.

Comment: How big are the spheres? How big is the box? Are the spheres allowed to drop in a specified direction, are new spheres allowed to jostle old spheres in a balanced way in an attempt to fit them? Do you stop immediately after a new sphere is blocked or keep going until there is no possible new sphere to fit? Details...

Comment: I did your simulation and got 30.9%

Comment: In effect, you ask about a special kind of 3D Renyi parking constant.